# Where can I find a resource for mathematically optimal plays?

Tags: betting-strategy, strategy, no-limit, poker-tools

So I've seen some streamer use an online tool that he used to analyse his plays. Specifically, the tool would tell him what actions are considered mathematically correct in the situation at hand.

I was wondering if anyone knows such a tool. I'll mainly be using it for pre-flop analysis and on small tables, but no limit. So if it only works for 2 or 3 players, that is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Poker has not been solved mathematically.  There is not one correct way to play poker.

But there are tools out there like equity calculators.  Equilab is as good free one.  You range your opponents and get the equity of your hand.

Tools can track metrics like if you are folding or bluffing the river too often.

On the river GTO can be solved but GTO is not always the best way to play poker.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a list of pocket cards run by a computer over a million random hands preflop with their winning percentage. The list is dramatically different from odds that you will see on televised WSOP events. https://www.gamblingsites.org/poker/texas-holdem/starting-hand-rankings/ I know this does not answer your entire question, only pre-flop analysis, but it has helped me a lot, especially with memorizing the top 10 hands.  For example, knowing that AQ offsuit is a no-no hand for many players, but AQ suited is a shove hand, especially in a critical situation, such as first to act, short-stacked, on or near the bubble.

Answer (score 0):

For shortstacked pre-flop spots I would highly recommend anyone to buy **icmizer 2**. Just purchase it for one month and see if you like it. After you use it for a month, you don't have to renew your subscription, but you have learned so much, for not a lot of money. It is definetely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The tools available ATM calculate your hand's equity verse a single hand or a range of hands you believe your opponent / opponents hold. 
You can then adjust this number based on the opponent tendencies in your current situation, but I don't think there is a tool that factors player specific tendencies (hud data) into the calculation in real time.